# Determine which core is running Node.js process at runtime

Tags: node.js

I was looking at the 'os' and 'process' module source and there does not appear to be a way to determine which core a node.js process is running on, before/during/after runtime.

I am looking for something like:

```
process.env.CORE_ID   //not real
```

I just want to confirm that different node.js processes are running on different cores. It seems reasonable that, although the operating system ultimately chooses which core a node.js process is executed on, we should be able to read that data once the OS starts the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible linux way:

```
function getPSR( pid, callback ) {
    var exec = require('child_process').execSync;

    var command = 'ps -A -o pid,psr -p ' + pid + ' | grep ' + pid + ' | grep -v grep |head -n 1 | awk \'{print $2}\'';

    var result = exec( command );

    return result.toString("utf-8").trim();
}

function getTIDs( pid ) {
    var exec = require('child_process').execSync;

    var command = 'ps -mo tid,psr -p ' + pid + ' | grep -v grep | awk \'/[0-9]/ {print("{\\042id\\042 : ", $1, ",\\042psr\\042:", $2, " }," )}\'';
    var tids = '[ ' + exec(command) + '{"id": false} ]';

    return JSON.parse(tids);
}

function setPSR( pid, psr ) {
    var exec = require('child_process').execSync;
    var command = 'taskset -pc ' + psr + ' ' + pid  + '; kill -STOP ' + pid + '; kill -CONT ' + pid;
    var result = exec(command);

    return result.toString("utf-8").trim();
}

function setTIDsPSR( pid, psr ) {
    var tids = getTIDs(pid);
    console.log(tids);
    for (var i in tids) {
    if (tids[i].id) {
        console.log( setPSR( tids[i].id, psr ) );
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Processes are not attached to specific core in any operating systems (except, maybe, in some real-time oriented one).

Processors (and cores) are resources that can be assigned to any process whenever it needs. One thread can be executed only in a single core at once, but cores are shared by all processes. The operating system is responsible to schedule processes over available cores. So, when any process is "paused" due to let execute (or continue execution of) another process in the same core, there is no reason to expect that process to be resumed in the same core next time.

This is slightly observable when you have single process with a high cpu cosumtion in a (multi-core) machine with a relative low cpu activity by simply executing `htop`. Then you could see that there is always a highly occupied core, but which core is it will change regularly.

Comment: well, the following statement is only conjecture, but perhaps there is a pool of available CPUs to run a process and you can dictate which pool iis available which process? Maybe you can talk about how the Node.js core cluster module fits in with what you are saying.

Comment: No. Processess (or threads) scheduling is an exclusive competence of the operating system. You can ask him to create a new process (or thread), but you can't decide on which physical processors will execute it.
I'm not sure if you could be confused with the Node thread pool which, in fact, is a pool of **threads** dedicated to attend async operations concurrently. See http://www.future-processing.pl/blog/on-problems-with-threads-in-node-js/

Comment: thanks, how do I access the Node.js thread pool from inside a node.js process?

Comment: This article explains it rather nicely. Basically, can't be done.
http://superuser.com/questions/867127/determine-which-cpu-a-process-is-running-on. If you want more assurance, use affinity.

Answer (score 6):

While trying to think about why you would want to know this kind of information, I think I understand the core of your confusion. Note that a process may switch cores multiple times per millisecond. The OS does a very good job of scheduling this, and I cannot imagine that performance is so much an issue that you would need to improve on this (because in this case you would be writing your own OS layer, and not in node). There will be absolutely NO observable delay between a process that runs on a core and that has to be started on that core, except possibly on embedded hardware with a custom OS.

Note that modern systems can even switch cores on and off. So imagine a webserver with 2 cores and 2 node processes serving requests. At night when there is not much work, the OS switches core 2 off, and both processes run happily both on core 1, serving the occasional request. Then when it gets busier, the OS starts the second core and most of the time both node processes will run at the same time, each on its own core. However note that the OS also has plenty of other processes (for instance, updating the realtime-clock). So it may very well be that at some point node process A runs on core 1, and node process B on core 2. Then core 1 is used to update the clock, while core 2 is still running B. Halfway through updating the clock however process B is stopped on core 2, and process A is started there. When the clock update is done, process B is started again on core 1. All of this happens in less than a microsecond.

So context switches happen millions of times a second on modern architectures, don't worry about them. Even if you find that at some point the 2 node processes run on different cores, there is no guarantee this is still true a microsecond later. And, again, probably the OS will do a much better job optimising this than you.

Now a thing that you could be interested in, is knowing if not for some reason the two processes ALWAYS run on the same core (e.g. because secretly they are not two processes, but one process, such as different requests to the same node server). This is something you only need to check for once. Just load both node instances fully, and check in top/process explorer/etc if their combined CPU usage is above 100%. If so, you can assume they are at least capable of running on different cores, and further assume that the OS will schedule them to different cores if they would benefit from this.

Comment: thanks Claude, that's right, I want to know upon starting more than one Node.js process, if the processes are indeed using multiple cores on the machine. Before i read these answers, I thought a Node.js process would only run on one core; but in reality that just means one core at one moment (this is obvious), but it doesn't mean that during the lifetime of the process it will be restricted to one core (what I thought prior). But yes, anyway, I want to know that when I use the cluster module or start child_processes with Node, if they are fulling using the resources (cores) on a machine.

Comment: So you should be able to test for this in some automatic way, putting artificial load on both, then programmatically seeing their combined cpu usage, but it seems useless to me --- since if they're independent once, they will be in subsequent runs. Actually, what might just do the trick is compare process ids since I'm quite sure that if they differ, they will run independently (although they could in theory still use locking to never be able to get above 100% cpu). Note that the opposite it not true: if the have the same pid, they may still be different threads, and able to run of two cores

Comment: Btw. Even if you find out how to query the core a thread runs on, it will be impossible to guarantee that both programs do this in the same clock tick, so it will still not tell you anything --- they may have switched cores many times between the two calls in the two programs.

Comment: I would think that if any process has a peak cpu usage > (100%/cores) then it's effectively using multiple cores.

Comment: @JDPeckham: I think my system reports CPU usage per core, so a peak CPU usage of 100% means 1 core fully loaded. A multi-threaded process can (and will in many cases) therefore use more than 100% CPU on my system (at least on my mac and afaik on linux with top/htop; may be different on other OSses / other programs. It's just about the definition of what is 100% CPU). So no need to divide by the number of cores.

Answer (score 2):

Try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodeaffinity

This works for Windows and Linux based OS except OSX.

```
var nc = require('nodeaffinity');

//Returns the cpus/cores (affinity mask) on which current node process is allowed to run 
//Failure returns -1 
console.log(nc.getAffinity()); 

//Sets process CPU affinity, here 3 means 011 i.e. process will be allowed to run on cpu0 and cpu1 
// returns same mask id success , if failure retuen -1. 
console.log(nc.setAffinity(3));
```